# How to "engrave" file data into the final executable?

Tags: java, programming-languages, executable

I would like to know how I could store my file in the final executable as raw bytes, that can be read by the program just like regular memory.
Like, I don't understand why file data that is NEVER manipulated during the program's runtime, have to be loaded "dynamically" instead of just being stored in the executable's data section.
Kind of like how you would use linkerscripts (typically non-bytecode languages) to map stuff in the executable's memory? Only that this would preferably also be done in Java.

Comment: Firstly, your question doesn't make much sense on first reading. Secondly, you should accept some answers if you want people to be motivated to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it'd take longer to load such an executable into memory. Also because it's 2011, and you have *files* and a *filesystem*.

About your first (and primary question), you don't need to muck about with anything as such. Just tack on your data to the end of the executable and add a final "offset" value to tell you how long it is.

### EDIT

I wrote my original answer in the context of a compiled executable, as with *C*. Since you've mentioned Java, afaik, you *can* put stuff in the final *JAR* and access it programmatically (since it's just an archive.)

Comment: But what if the file was only like 50 characters long?

Comment: @Benjamin What file? If it's 50 bytes long, then you have: Executable + 50 bytes of file + 4 bytes integer with offset (from end of file.)